# How to make a Word document template with selectable sections?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I want to make a Word template for a standardized contract for my sales team. Depending on what the customers wants, some sections of the template may not apply. Is there a way to let the salesperson check boxes for the parts they need and automatically add those parts to the right place in the template?

I know about Quick Parts, but they require the salesperson to go to the right place in the document and select the right quick part. I'd prefer something that's more standardized.

Comment: I just answered a duplicate: https://superuser.com/a/1243032/375935