# Automatically build a word document based on user selections

Tags: microsoft-word

often I need to create proposal documents for customers which have many common elements. For example, I have the following sections of text:

- Company Introduction
- Information about Product A
- Information about Product B
- Information about Product C

etc...

I'd like to present a popup to the user on opening the document which allows them to tick the relevant sections which would then be added to the document (or the irrelevant sections removed).

I'm looking for the simplest way to create this. I'm thinking of two possible approaches:

1. Add each section as quick part, and somehow have the tick box automatically add the right quick part at the end of the document.
2. Create the whole document with all sections and somehow remove sections automatically if not required.

I've been searching for a while but no luck. Any pointers would be good. Ideally I'd like to do this without any coding, but if that's not possible anything simple considered that is easily maintainable.

Thanks!

Comment: Related, but unanswered: [How to make a Word document template with selectable sections?](https://superuser.com/questions/956032/how-to-make-a-word-document-template-with-selectable-sections?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [phraseexpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) can do something like this.

Their demo includes something similar. 
Press or type a shortcut/string then a gui pops up and you can select boilerplate elements that generates a doc file. Includes signatures and more.

---

### Step 1: Customize the default demo generator with your text and shortcut/autotext.

[image: image1]

### Step 2: When triggered, use the GUI popup to select the elements you want.

[image: imagw2]

### Step 3: Export the file as a word doc.[image: image3]

I'm not affiliated with them. I don't like their website (no https, zero support or bug report options for non-premium users). But it's a good tool overal.